# Redirect all IPs except those whitelisted

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to protect some subdomains from the public. Restriction should be done against a whitelist of IPs.
Infinite loop due to the redirect is not a problem as its not the www-domain.

I tried this http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=2411725, but couldnt get it to work.

However I did try this first

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^213\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteRule ^/.* http://www.mydomain.com [R]
```

.. but didnt work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to combine the `RewriteCond` directives with AND instead of OR as you want to redirect if both conditions are true (therefor the IP address is neither *X* nor *Y*). So try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^213\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R]
```

Comment: If you want to be explicit about the redirect like me, (either permanent 301 or temporary 302) then alter to flag to something like `[R=302]`

Answer (score 6):

This kind of thing is actually exactly what Apache's `Allow` and `Deny` directives are intended for. Inside the `<VirtualHost>` block for the domain you want to restrict access to, put this:

```
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from 123.45.67.89
    Deny from 213.45.67.89
</Location>
```

However, this would produce a 403 (forbidden) error, which doesn't redirect to your `www` domain by default. I think you can make it do so by adding the directive

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com
```